# Close File, Still in Use

Tags: files, recentf

I have a problem, where after I edit a file on a USB stick and close the file with C-x k, Emacs still has a grip on the file until this message appears a few minutes later:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp tramp-recentf-exclude-predicate)
  string-match(tramp-recentf-exclude-predicate "/sudo:root@localhost:/mnt/sdk1/config.txt")
  (not (string-match (car rl) filename))
  (and rl (not (string-match (car rl) filename)))
  (while (and rl (not (string-match (car rl) filename))) (setq rl (cdr rl)))
  (let ((case-fold-search recentf-case-fold-search) (rl recentf-exclude)) (while (and rl (not (string-match (car rl) filename))) (setq rl (cdr rl))) (null rl))
  recentf-include-p("/sudo:root@localhost:/mnt/sdk1/config.txt")
  (and (file-readable-p filename) (recentf-include-p filename) filename)
  (lambda (filename) (and (file-readable-p filename) (recentf-include-p filename) filename))("/sudo:root@localhost:/mnt/sdk1/config.txt")
  mapcar((lambda (filename) (and (file-readable-p filename) (recentf-include-p filename) filename)) ("/sudo:root@localhost:/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" "/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" "/mnt/sdk1/cmdline.txt" "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/home/b0ef/agenda/shopping.org" "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/ds/platf..." "/home/b0ef/agenda/quasar-agenda.org" "/home/b0ef/Downloads/2937359.png" "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." "/mnt/b53d6116-b84e-4cbb-a7d0-cc1cfb3089d9/cloud/jh..." ...))
  (delq nil (mapcar #'(lambda (filename) (and (file-readable-p filename) (recentf-include-p filename) filename)) recentf-list))
  (setq recentf-list (delq nil (mapcar #'(lambda (filename) (and (file-readable-p filename) (recentf-include-p filename) filename)) recentf-list)))
  (let ((count (length recentf-list))) (setq recentf-list (delq nil (mapcar #'(lambda (filename) (and (file-readable-p filename) (recentf-include-p filename) filename)) recentf-list))) (setq count (- count (length recentf-list))) (message "%s removed from the list" (cond ((= count 0) "No file") ((= count 1) "One file") (t (format "%d files" count)))))
  recentf-cleanup()
  tramp-recentf-cleanup((tramp-file-name "sudo" "root" nil "localhost" nil "/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" nil))
  run-hook-with-args(tramp-recentf-cleanup (tramp-file-name "sudo" "root" nil "localhost" nil "/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" nil))
  tramp-cleanup-connection((tramp-file-name "sudo" "root" nil "localhost" nil "/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" nil) keep-debug nil keep-processes)
  tramp-timeout-session((tramp-file-name "sudo" "root" nil "localhost" nil "/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" nil))
  apply(tramp-timeout-session (tramp-file-name "sudo" "root" nil "localhost" nil "/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" nil))
  timer-event-handler([t 25679 31419 16066 nil tramp-timeout-session ((tramp-file-name "sudo" "root" nil "localhost" nil "/mnt/sdk1/config.txt" nil)) nil 989000 nil])
```

Any pointers as to what it's doing here?;)

Comment: What is the value of `recentf-exclude` at the time of the failure? It seems to include predicates (i.e. boolean functions) which the `C-h v recentf-exclude` description of the variable allows, but the code of the function `recentf-include-p` seems to ignore that possibility. You might try to post the code of that function here to verify. If so, it's a bug in `recentf` so you might want to upgrade the `recentf` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug in `recentf`. The version of `recentf-include-p` I have looks like this:

```el
(defun recentf-include-p (filename)
  "Return non-nil if FILENAME should be included in the recent list.
That is, if it doesn't match any of the `recentf-exclude' checks."
  (let ((case-fold-search recentf-case-fold-search)
        (checks recentf-exclude)
        (keepit t))
    (while (and checks keepit)
      ;; If there was an error in a predicate, err on the side of
      ;; keeping the file.  (Bug#5843)
      (setq keepit (not (ignore-errors
                          (if (stringp (car checks))
                              ;; A regexp
                              (string-match (car checks) filename)
                            ;; A predicate
                            (funcall (car checks) filename))))
            checks (cdr checks)))
    keepit))
```

It looks like yours doesn't have the `(stringp (car checks))` check, so it goes directly into the `string-match` with something that is not a string. It may that your version of `recentf` is not (ahem) recent enough, so you might want to upgrade. My version is 21.1 and it seems to handle predicates properly.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I have an ancient recentf.el file in my .elisp directory, but I don't understand how it got picked up, cause I have no explicit load of that file. Is it possible to figure out how it was loaded?;)

Comment: Autoloads? If that directory is in your `load-path`, any file in it can be autoloaded at any time.